# why doesn't request lib provide all cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, session-cookies

I'm not understanding why the python requests library isn't pulling in all cookies. For examples, I am running this code

```
import requests

a_session = requests.Session()
a_session.get('https://google.com/')
session_cookies = a_session.cookies
cookies_dictionary = session_cookies.get_dict()

print(cookies_dictionary)
```

But I only get the cookie "1P_JAR" even though there should be several cookies.
[list of cookies shown up on inspector pannel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdHTT.png)

Ultimately I'm trying to figure out why its choosing only that 1 cookie and not the others because I'm trying to build my own application that generates a cookie but when I run this script on my application I get back and empty list even though the inspector shows that I have generated a cookie.

Comment: Requests provides exactly what it received from server.

Comment: Are the other cookies not coming from the server then? How can I read the other cookies from python?

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is set by a server response to a specific request.

Your basic google.com request only sets that cookie, which you can observe by the set-cookie header.

The other cookies are probably set by other requests or even the js code. Requests doesn't evaluate or run js and thus doesn't make any other requests.

If you don't want to completely reverse engeneer every single cookie, the way to go would be to simulate a browser by using Selenium + Chrome Driver or a similar solution.